# ERROR TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I create simple form then i got An Error.
**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('/posts','PostsController');
```

**PostsController**

```
public function create()
{
    return view('posts.create');
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request->all();
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts/aap')

@section('content')
    <form  method="post" action="/posts">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Title">

        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>


@yield('footer')
```

** i want to get title filed data ** when i press submit button i got This Error
[image]

iam beginner can anyone help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need csrf verifcation you can remove:

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken
```

from `/app/Http/Resquests/Kernel.php`

If you need csrf verifcation you can add hidden field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>" />
```

Or you can add meta tag to your main layout for all project:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>" />
```

Comment: can u plz explain about csrf verification because iam following one tutorial,it doesn't enter any hidden field but his code is working**,WHY?**

Comment: if I enter hidden field ,it shows its values on the source code,then any security issues?

Comment: I think his code works, because he disabled csrf verifcation. You can read more here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf . If you'll add hidden field you'll not have security issues, because laravel generates a csrf token for each active user session.

Comment: Thanks alot  @M.Max,for helping me :)